# Does the Monero executable for Windows not have a code signing certificate?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, security, getmonero-website, download

I was getting really nervous about using the Monero wallet. It seemed like the download page was [ww.getmonero.org/downloads](http://ww.getmonero.org/downloads), which I thought was weird. Additionally, the executable for Windows wasn't signed at all.

It this correct? If it is, it should change.

Monero is one of the most steal-able cryptos.

Answer (score 0):

The website URL is correct. Once you've downloaded, you can check against the supplied hash and verify the signature of the hashes list. Details on the [releases page](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases) of the project (where you can also download from).

Instructions on how to verify your download can be found [here](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/verification-windows-beginner.html).

Comment: So there is no code signing cert? Seems like a very very bad policy. I'm technical enough to verify, but ... really?

Comment: The hashes are signed. It's another way of achieving the same result but without having to individually sign each download - sign one list of hashes.

Comment: The trouble I see is that I don't necessarily know the true domain name (which I was nervous bout the two different download pages), so I thought that I could be getting phished on even the verification process. Additionally, if we want more mainstream adoption, it would be a much better policy to have Microsoft not complain about legit downloads.   Anyway, thank you. You've made me less nervous.

Comment: The releases are always listed on the projects releases page I linked in the answer, along with the signed hashes. This works almost identically to Bitcoin (and other open-source software). With regards to signing for OSs such as for  Microsoft/Apple, that's a very different scenario and requires getting a developer certificate from MS/Apple.

Comment: And as for the domain name, getmonero.org is the official domain name. There are various *host* names, ww is one of them.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately "ww." looks like a scammy version of "www." That combined with having 2 download pages and Microsoft warning scared me a lot.  Perhaps the download pages to be collapsed to just one. The "ww" host name seems to be a bad policy as well.

Comment: Some people are unfamiliar with GitHub and prefer a shiny website with big download links. Some are more familiar with open-source development and prefer to have the releases where the code is. Everyone can verify their downloads and check both download locations. Soon there will also be reproducible builds for even more verification.

Comment: Seems to me that the only people can feel quite confident in securing there own coins are much more technically savvy people (and non lazy people).  Making it more difficult, encouraging people to leave their coins on exchanges, consequently encouraging centralization and leaving coins available for centralized theft. With $100M++ market cap, it seems like more ease of use should be in order.

Comment: Also, both www and ww versions both hit the same page. A google search for "monero download" also returns the www version first.

Comment: "it seems like more ease of use should be in order" <- there's plenty of instructions and this is really no different to bitcoin downloads.

Comment: "The trouble I see is that I don't necessarily know the true domain name" <- Correct. Neither do newcomers to bitcoin know the difference between the .com and the .org which are very different projects. Anyone using cryptocurrencies should at least know what they are downloading is the correct thing (hence good that you checked and I hope my timely answer has helped you).